# Existe algum jeito mais fácil para textfield de telefone?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

int length = [self getLength:textField.text];
//NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

if(length == 11)
{
    if(range.length == 0)
        return NO;
}

if(length == 2)
{
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",num];
    if(range.length > 0)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
}
else if(length == 7)
{
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
    //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:2],[num substringFromIndex:2]];
    if(range.length > 0)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:2],[num substringFromIndex:2]];
}

return YES;
}

-(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{

mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

int length = [mobileNumber length];
if(length > 10)
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

}


return mobileNumber;
}


-(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{

mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = [mobileNumber length];

return length;


}
```

Comment: Por favor, explique melhor seu problema com o código atual. Só o título e um copy/paste de código deixam a pergunta extremamente pobre. Confira os guias [ask] e **[about]**. E bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tenho algo genérico, que funciona também com telefone, utilizando máscara. É assim, tenho uma subclasse de `UITextField` que chamei de `CustomTextField`. Meu arquivo `.h` é mais ou menos assim:

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mask;

- (BOOL)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

E no meu arquivo de implementação `.m`, assim:

```
NSString *filteredFromStringWithFilter(NSString *string, NSString *filter) {
    NSUInteger onOriginal = 0, onFilter = 0, onOutput = 0;
    char outputString[([filter length])];
    BOOL done = NO;

    while(onFilter < [filter length] && !done) {
        char filterChar = [filter characterAtIndex:onFilter];
        char originalChar = onOriginal >= string.length ? '\0' : [string characterAtIndex:onOriginal];
        switch (filterChar) {
            case '#':
                if (originalChar=='\0') {
                    done = YES;
                    break;
                }
                if(isdigit(originalChar)) {
                    outputString[onOutput] = originalChar;
                    onOriginal++;
                    onFilter++;
                    onOutput++;
                } else {
                    onOriginal++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                outputString[onOutput] = filterChar;
                onOutput++;
                onFilter++;
                if (originalChar == filterChar)
                    onOriginal++;
                break;
        }
    }
    outputString[onOutput] = '\0'; // Cap the output string

    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputString];
}

- (BOOL)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (self.mask) {
        NSString *changedString = [self.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        if (range.length == 1 && // Only do for single deletes
            string.length < range.length &&
            [[self.text substringWithRange:range] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSInteger location = changedString.length-1;
            if (location > 0) {
                for (; location > 0; location--) {
                    if (isdigit([changedString characterAtIndex:location])) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                changedString = [changedString substringToIndex:location];
            }
        }

        [self setText:filteredFromStringWithFilter(changedString, self.mask)];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

E no meu `ViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
    return [(CustomTextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:string];
}
```

Pronto, assim fica genérico para utilizar máscara como quiser, por exemplo, utilizando a interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parabéns pela solução!

Comment: Mas para funcionar, comigo eu precisei adicionar um delegate do campo ao ViewController - no inspetor do storyboard clica em ctrl no elemento e arrasta para o ViewController (ícone amarelinho) e escolhe "delegate" e funfou lindo!