# Máscara para UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Como aplicar máscara em um `UITextField`? Encontrei alguns meios de como aplicar uma máscara em um `UITextField`, porém não me parecia alguma coisa muito correta de se fazer. Pode ser um exemplo de máscara para telefone, bem simples. Pode ser em Swift ou Objective-C.

OBS: uma maneira que não pareça uma "gambiarra"

Comment: não percebi a tua questão, o que queres dizer com uma "mascara"? uma expressão regular para validar o text?

Comment: Seria definir um padrão para a String do UITextField. Exemplo: Campo de telefone: (##)####-####

Comment: Ou também exemplo de campo de valor: $##,##

Comment: Para o caso do telefone, respondi outra pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10300/4337). Para valor monetário, você pode tentar algo [daqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8190/formatar-moeda-em-um-uitextfield).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar [VMaskTextField](https://github.com/viniciusmo/VMaskTextField) onde apenas tens que indicar uma máscara para assumir a formatação.

Por exemplo:

```
self.maskTextField.mask = @"(##) ####-####";
```

Outros exemplos:

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 1):

Tens que implementar o método "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" do TextField.

Dentro do método aplica a validação do texto que pretendes sempre que houver uma alteração no texto.
Uma optima solução que cheguei a [usar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709450/uitextfield-format-in-xx-xx-xxx), permite-te aplicar facilmente uma reg e o texto para obter esse mesmo texto formatado.

Analisa o codigo e aplica as tuas necessidades