# Como uso VMaskTextField com o Swift?

Tags: swift

Como faço para usar VMaskTextField com o Swift?

self.comVM.mask = "###(##)##"

Comment: Poderá servir esta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40229/máscara-para-uitextfield/40293#40293

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var comVM: VMaskTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        comVM.mask = "(##) ####-####";
        comVM.delegate = self;
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return comVM.shouldChangeCharactersInRange(range, replacementString: string);
    }
}
```

Não se esqueça de trocar a classe do `UITextField` para `VMaskTextField` no storyboard/nib .

Comment: Aqui nao funcionou.. =/ fica dando essa error 2017-08-02 17:18:45.161 iSkyNote[29691:421271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField setTextWithMask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7afb7450'